# how to stop counter after hide modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, modal-dialog, counter

I want to count up only when a modal is shown. but somehow after the modal is closed, the counter is still going up. what is wrong with my code below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var seconds = 0;
    $('#mymodal #show_seconds').val(seconds);

    if ($(this).is(':visible') {
      setInterval(function() {
        ++seconds;
        $('#mymodal #show_seconds').val(seconds);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $('#mymodal #show_seconds').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript functions are not automatically destroyed for you. You have to manually clear the interval.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var interval;

  $('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var seconds = 0;
    $('#mymodal #show_seconds').val(seconds);

    if ($(this).is(':visible') {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        ++seconds;
        $('#mymodal #show_seconds').val(seconds);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $('#mymodal #show_seconds').val('');
    }
  });

  $('#mymodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

    if( interval ) {

      clearInterval( interval );

    }

  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how to use "setInterval" in Javascript.

```
var mySetInterval = setInterval(function(){},1000);//create a valuable;
clearInterval(myVar);// delete a valuable;
```

please see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp